# PHP Aligning Array Key Values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, key

I've Googled it for two days, and tried looking at the PHP manual, and I still can't remember that function that aligns the key values for PHP arrays.

All I'm looking for is the function that takes this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 3
    [7] => 4
    [9] => 5
)
```

And converts it into this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
```

Basically, the array is first sorted by key (their values attached to them stay with them), then all the keys are set to all the counting numbers, consecutively, without skipping any number (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...). I saw it being used with ksort() a few months ago, and can't see to remember or find this elusive function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you see, this one is hard, because the general description on the PHP array functions page does not say that this function does what you're looking for.

But you can sort the array using `ksort()`, and then use this: `array_values()` . From the page from the PHP manual:

> `array_values()` returns all the values from the input array and indexes numerically the array.

Comment: I don't understand the use of `ksort()` here. `array_values()` should be enough because we are deleting the keys anyway. If anything there should be a `sort()` (on key values).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_merge`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$array = array_merge($array);
```

It will reindex values with numeric keys.

**Update:** Using `array_values` as proposed in [@LostInTheCode's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530691/php-aligning-array-key-values/4530720#4530720) is probably more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

```
function array_reset_index_keys($array)
{
    $return = array();foreach($array as $k => $v){$return[] = $v;}return $return;
}
```

And then use like a regular function, should re index the array

you can also use native functions such as `array_values` which returns the values of an array into a single dimension array, causing it to be re indexed .

Comment: What do you mean with 2d array? `array_values` just returns the values. There is only one dimension.

Comment: yea, i was adding native alternatives while you commented sir :)

Comment: I was changing my comment while you commented sir ;)

Comment: 2d was meant to be 'single dimension'