# How to sort/order an array by it's keys?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, key

This array has no [0] and [2] keys.

```
Array
(
[1] => 5.2836

[3] => 2.5749

[4] => 134.19

[5] => 5.8773

[6] => 1.3504
....
```

How can I change it to:

```
Array
(
[0] => 5.2836

[1] => 2.5749

[2] => 134.19

[3] => 5.8773

[4] => 1.3504
....
```

Is there any inbuilt function for such a task in php?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530691/php-aligning-array-key-values).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [**`array_values()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

> ... returns all the values from the input array and indexes numerically the array.

Note this is not *sorting* or *ordering* the keys, it is *reindexing*  the array.

Comment: e.g. `$array = array_values($array);` will "renumber" the keys.

Answer (score 0):

You are not really sorting, it looks like you want to reassign keys to the values.  try this:

```
<?php
    $array = array( 1 => 5.2836,  3 => 2.5749,  4 => 134.19,  5 => 5.8773,  6 => 1.3504 );
    $x=0;
    foreach($array as $key => $val){
        $new_array[$x] = $val;
        $x++;
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($new_array);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```